# Try to split a string with particular regex expression

Tags: regex, split, python-re

i'm trying to split a string using 2 separator and regex. My string is for example

"test 10 20 middle 30 - 40 mm".

and i would like to split in ["test 10", "20 middle 30", "40 mm"]. So, splittin dropping '  -  ' and the space between 2 digits.
I tried to do

```
result = re.split(r'[\d+] [\d+]', s)
> ['test 1', '0 middle 30 - 40 mm']

result2 = re.split(r' - |{\d+} {\d+}', s)
> ['test 10 20 middle 30', '40 mm']
```

Is there any reg expression to split in ['test 10', '20 middle 30', '40 mm'] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<=\d)\s+(?:-\s+)?(?=\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ojZcTZ/1).

**Details**

- `(?<=\d)` - a digit must appear immediately on the left
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:-\s+)?` - an optional sequence of a `-` followed with 1+ whitespaces
- `(?=\d)` - a digit must appear immediately on the right.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jrVysM):

```
import re
text = "test 10 20 middle 30 - 40 mm"
print( re.split(r'(?<=\d)\s+(?:-\s+)?(?=\d)', text) )
# => ['test 10', '20 middle 30', '40 mm']
```

Answer (score 1):

Data

```
k="test 10 20 middle 30 - 40 mm"
```

Please Try

```
result2 = re.split(r"(^[a-z]+\s\d+|\^d+\s[a-z]+|\d+)$",k)
result2
```

`**^[a-z]**`-match lower case alphabets at the start of the string and greedily to the left **`+`** followed by:

```
 **`\s`** white space characters
 **`\d`** digits greedily matched to the left
```

**`|`** or match start of string with digits **`\d+`** also matched greedily to the left and followed by:

```
  `**\s**` white space characters
   **`a-z`** lower case alphabets greedily matched to the left
```

**`|`** or match digits greedily to the left **`\d+`** end the string **`$`**

Output
[image]